# iOS app crashes when closing/opening quickly

Tags: ios, xcode

The main issue with this bug is that I can't have my device connected to Xcode to debug, since to get it to crash, I have to close the app (terminating the debug session), and open again quickly. Keyword: quickly... I don't have time to close, and rebuild through Xcode, otherwise it won't crash for me (needs to be within a second or two)... I don't see anything notable in Organizer > Crashes... I'm not looking for specific solutions since I don't have an error code yet, I'm just looking for ideas/ways to get this error code.

Again, just to clarify, this crash can only happen within a second or two of closing the app. Open > Close > Open again within a second -> Crash. The crash happens consistently.

Comment: Did you found the reason for the issue? I have exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only your app that's doing this. If you have opened some nested VCs and you quickly close/reopen the app - it crashes. I have experienced this crash on every single app, even the native iOS apps like AppStore or Notes.
In my opinion this is because when you kill it and relaunch it very quickly, the killing process wasn't finish so it terminates the new session.

Anyway this is bug in iOS for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug in your app, this thing happen on Simulator when you consistently close open app on simulator like when you launch the app soo fast that the previous session is still not cleared from memory then your app close immediately and you might thought that it is bug in your app but it is not.

Comment: I'm not using a simulator though... It happens for me (and others) on a real iPhone with the version of this app downloaded from the App Store. It does seem to have something to do with the memory not being cleared in time, but it's happening in a production environment without using the simulator - unfortunately. When I looked online for this prior to asking the question here, all I saw was talk about it being a simulator issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same issue after updated my Xcode from 14.3 to 15.2. Whenever I run the application through Xcode. It was successfully launch and I was able to use the application, If I kill the application and again launch through app icon taps. It was crashing.

**I my case I tried this.**

Go to your Xcode **target** and select **general tab**, scroll down and expend **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content**, you'll see your frameworks listed there select **Embed & Sign** from dropdown.

Once you done with this. Select **Build Phase** tab and expend **Link Binary With Libraries** Select all framework from optional to **required**.

here is attached screenshot of **Link Binary With Libraries** section.

[image]